# ~150ms on a 2 million rows MySQL MyISAM table

Tags: mysql, performance, myisam, mysql-5.6

I'm learning about MySQL performance with a pet project consisting of ~2million rows + ~600k rows (two MyISAM tables). A range query using BETWEEN on two INT(10) indexed columns, LIMITed to 1 returned result takes about 160ms (including an INNER JOIN). I figure my configuration isn't optimised and am looking for some advice on how to either diagnose, or perhaps "common configuration".

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/fl0w/69df3e779f55a4a9d541) containing both tables, the query and the contents of my.cnf.

I created the b-tree index after inserting all data which was imported from a CSV file from [MaxMinds open database](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/). I tried two separate, and now a combined index with no difference in performance.

I'm running this locally on a Macbook Pro clocking at 2,6GHz (i5) and 8GB 1600MHz RAM. MySQL is installed using the downloadable binary from mysql's download page *(unable to supply a third link because my rep is to low)*. It's a default installation with no major additions to the my.cnf config-file, included in the gist (located under /usr/local/mysql-5.6.xxx/ directory on my system).

My concern is that I'm reaching ~160ms which indicates to me that I'm missing something. I've considered compressing the table but I have a feeling that I'm missing other configurations. Also the myisampack wasn't in my PATH (I think) so I'm considering other optimisations before I explore this further.

Any advice is appreciated!

```
$ mysql --version
/usr/local/mysql-5.6.23-osx10.8-x86_64/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.23, for osx10.8 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE `blocks` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `begin_range` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `end_range` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `_location_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `begin_range` (`begin_range`,`end_range`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2008839 DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii;

CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `region` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` float NOT NULL,
  `longitude` float NOT NULL,
  `metro_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `area_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=641607 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Query

```
SELECT locations.latitude, locations.longitude
FROM blocks
INNER JOIN locations ON blocks._location_id = locations.id
WHERE INET_ATON('139.130.4.5') BETWEEN begin_range AND end_range
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

Edit;
Updated gist with EXPLAIN on the SELECT, also posted here for convenience.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT locations.latitude, locations.longitude FROM blocks INNER JOIN locations ON blocks._location_id = locations.id WHERE INET_ATON('94.137.106.123') BETWEEN begin_range AND end_range LIMIT 0, 1;

+----+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type   | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref                       | rows    | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | blocks    | range  | begin_range   | begin_range | 4       | NULL                      | 1095345 | Using index condition; Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | locations | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY     | 4       | geoip.blocks._location_id |       1 | NULL                               |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Edit 2; Included data into the question for convenience.

Comment: You might want to run an EXPLAIN and post the results.

Comment: It is pointless to have index as `(begin_range, end_range)`. It would be used as if it was just `(begin_range)`. So, it is better to have index `(begin_range)`, because it is smaller - less bytes to read from disk (though benefit is relatively small). You can try to add second index on `(end_range)`, but I doubt MySQL would use both indexes in this query. Try and check `explain`.

Comment: It is not entirely useless. If all the information required is in the index itself the table does not have to be read to retrieve the rest of the data. I would actually try a combined index on `[begin_range, end_range, _location_id]` or `[_location_id, begin_range, end_range]`. Order matters. This way the join can be performed from the index itself.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I tried both with no real impact on performance (in my case). I'll try ontrack's suggestion after lunch - however, adding the INNER JOIN added about ~5ms to the overall response time.

Comment: Otherwise. 160ms is not necessarily bad. Given the reason given by Vladimir. After passing `begin_range` a lot of data stil has to be read to verify it is below `end_range`. You could try improving your mysql configuration itself so you don't have to read data from harddisk. But I am not sure from your question if this is a development machine or the definitive platform.

Comment: @ontrack Well I'm trying to learn about my mistake here, so in this case it's on a local dev machine - yes. However, I would like to use this in a production environment that would generate about 5-30 requests per second. My point is that if I can't bring a single query response time down, how would this scale in production under load?

Comment: A range select is difficult because you can't use the index for filtering anymore after the first column. However you can solve the problem by writing your data or your query differently.This means a single column with every address in a range. Probably not advisable, but maybe you don't actually need all addresses. If you have all addresses or your blocks are of equal size you can drop the `end_range` column in the query and use `WHERE begin_range>=address ORDER BY begin_range ASC LIMIT 1`. Like this https://andy.wordpress.com/2007/12/16/fast-mysql-range-queries-on-maxmind-geoip-tables/

Comment: How many results without the `LIMIT` clause?

Comment: @RandomSeed Should always result in 1 row. However, it could be that there's a few IPs that would result with more - but that would be a data specific defect.

Comment: @ontrack Yes, that does work far better. And you're right, in my case I could just skip the range check. However, the BETWEEN query and the WHERE return two different results - but I guess this has to do with me not understanding the data yet.

Comment: The execution plan could indicate that ~1M rows match the "unlimited" query. Please confirm how many rows do match the `WHERE` clause without `LIMIT` (`SELECT COUNT(*) ...`).

Comment: @RandomSeed with the BETWEEN condition the result is always 1 row w/o the LIMIT. I'm going to try the solution provided by Rick James down below during the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, and the normal approach (which your code exemplifies) leads to hitting 1095345 rows.  I have an approach that can do that query in *one* disk hit, even the cache is cold.

Excerpts from http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges :

The Situation

Your data includes a large set of non-overlapping 'ranges'. These could be IP addresses, datetimes (show times for a single station), zipcodes, etc.

You have pairs of start and end values; one 'item' belongs to each such 'range'. So, instinctively, you create a table with start and end of the range, plus info about the item. Your queries involve a WHERE clause that compares for being between the start and end values.

The Problem

Once you get a large set of items, performance degrades. You play with the indexes, but find nothing that works well. The indexes fail to lead to optimal functioning because the database does not understand that the ranges are non-overlapping.

The Solution

I will present a solution that enforces the fact that items cannot have overlapping ranges. The solution builds a table to take advantage of that, then uses Stored Routines to get around the clumsiness imposed by it.