# Performance improvement of ip-geolocation query

Tags: mysql, lookup, ip-geolocation

Suppose a table `location_block` that translates ipv4 addresses to geolocation:

```
columns: ipmin <INT UNSIGNED> | ipmax <INT UNSIGNED> | id_location <MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED>
indexes: ipmin <UNIQUE> | ipmax <UNIQUE>
size: 2Mi rows
storage engine: InnoDB
ps: no overlapping among ip ranges
```

You could geolocate an ipv4 address by executing the following `BETWEEN` query:

```
SELECT `id_location`
FROM `location_block`
WHERE '1234567890' BETWEEN `ipmin` AND `ipmax`
LIMIT 1
```

However, this is quite slow (~1 sec).

**Improvement Proposal**
According to @RickJames ([Blocks of Addresses](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges)) it is possible to optimize this `BETWEEN` query by scanning only half of the table. The code is also provided ([Reference implementation for IPv4](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipv4.sql)).

However, I'm struggling somewhat with this code. I have the impression that it is possible to simplify it and still obtain some of the described performance improvement.

**Question**
Is it possible to make a simpler code? Preferably a 'readable query' or a single procedure? How? Would it be faster than the `BETWEEN` query?

## Follow-up

For the records, finally I've developed the procedure below which is running much faster (~1ms):

```
main:BEGIN
    
    DECLARE _ipmax INT unsigned;
    DECLARE _idloc MEDIUMINT unsigned;

    SELECT `ipmax`, `id_location`
    INTO _ipmax, _idloc
    FROM `location_block`
    WHERE `ipmin` <= _ip
    ORDER BY `ipmin`  DESC
    LIMIT 1;

    IF( (_idloc IS NULL) OR (_ip > _ipmax) ) THEN
        LEAVE main;
    END IF;

END
```

Comment: Have a look at [Blocks of Addresses, such as IP Addresses](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges). It makes use of the non-overlapping ranges to optimize the lookup.

Comment: The blog contains sample code (under [Reference implementation of IPv4](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipv4.sql)). You may want to experiment with it, and if something doesn't work, you should ask specific questions (otherwise, all we can do is to repeat what is already written in the blog. The implementation should solve your exact problem). Also, [Rick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766831/rick-james) is a member on stackoverflow, so he might have a look at your problem if you get stuck somewhere [with his code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28711483/6248528).

Answer (score 0):

Have you left your buffer size at the default? If so, try editing your my.cnf and setting `innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G`