# Trying to improve sluggish MySQL query lookup

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have a MySQL database of about 3 million records:

[image]

It contains IP geo-location information as such:

[image]

And the table is defined as follows:

[image]

My goal is to locate an entry by an arbitrary IP address. I use the following SQL for that (PHP syntax):

```
$n_ip = ip2long("106.87.84.64");    //or 1784108096
$res = mysqli_query($link, 
    "SELECT * FROM `ip2location` WHERE `ip_from`<='$n_ip' AND `ip_to`>='$n_ip' LIMIT 1");
```

That query above seems to take about 4.5 seconds.

I was wondering, is there something I can do to improve performance on it?

Comment: Of the 4.5 seconds, how much is execution time and how much is fetch time? Also, do you _need_ all columns to be returned? Requesting just the columns you need will be faster.

Comment: the index idx_ip_to is redundant; also since ip_from is the is PK, idx_ip_from_to should be unique

Comment: If your IP ranges don't overlap, you can try [Blocks of Addresses, such as IP Addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28711483). On the other hand, 4.5s seems long (the linked question with a similar number of ip ranges tries to get down from 160ms), so something else might be going on; so if you want to work with this query, add some details: the execution plan (the output of `explain SELECT * FROM ...`), myisam configuration (especially `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'key_buffer_size';`) and/or have you tried it with innodb?

Comment: @PeterHe yes, good point. Thanks. I removed `idx_ip_to` index and made `idx_ip_from_to` unique. Although, besides freeing up some space, it didn't make it run faster.

Comment: @Solarflare: for the `show variable` I'm getting `key_buffer_size 33554432` and for `explain` I'm getting: [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/GybMW6o.png)

Comment: I hope you are not using MyISAM.  (`key_buffer_size` does not apply to InnoDB.)